# C++ std::set unable to use operator + on iterator because compilation error

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, stl, iterator, stdset

So I encountered a weird iterator bug ONLY on std::set : I'm unable to do a simple thing like (it + 1) on an iterator without a compilation error
Try to compile this yourself :

```
void setBug()
{
    std::set<int> values;

    for (auto it = values.cbegin();
         it != values.cend(); ++it) {
        if ((it + 1) != values.end())
            values.insert(*it / *(it + 1));
    }
}
```

error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::_*1::*_tree_const_iterator *, long>' and 'int')
if ((it + 1) != values.end())

error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::_*1::*_tree_const_iterator *, long>' and 'int')
values.insert(*it / *(it + 1));

compiler version :
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix

I found a dirty solution : (auto it2 = ++it ; --it) which works, but this is really dirty...

Has somebody an explanation ? Is std::set broken ?

Thanks.

Comment: it is a bidirectional iterator, not a random access one

Comment: `auto it2 = it; ++it2;` would be cleaner than your dirty solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`std::set` iterators are [bidirectional iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator). These do not support increment via the addition operator. You need to increment then step by step, or use [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) or [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance), both of which which do the same behind the scenes. This operation will be O(N) regardless.